# How to Use ModernCV Icons with Classic Style CV

Tags: errors, formatting, packages, resume

I really like the style of [this CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/thomas-jansson-cv) -- I am not sure if the style has a name, but I have seen it many times. Here is the source code for my CV:

```
\documentclass[margin,line,pifont,palatino,courier]{res}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[latin1] { inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\topmargin .5in
\oddsidemargin -.2in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=5.8in
\textheight=9.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\topmargin=-0.2in
\textheight=9in
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{{\footnotesize Curriculum Vitae \thepage}}


\newenvironment{list1}{
\begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
  \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}{\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}{
\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
  \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}


\name{<Name here> \vspace*{.1in} \hspace{3.85in} Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{resume}

\section{\sc Contact Information}

\vspace{.05in}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3.75in}p{2in}}
<Address Line 1> & <phone number here> \\
<Name of School> & \texttt{\href{mailto:<email here>}{<email here>}} \\
<City, State, Zip> & \texttt{\href{<website here>}{<website here>}} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{\sc Education}

\section{\sc Teaching}

\section{\sc Employment}

\section{\sc Research}

\section{\sc Last updated} November 15, 2014

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to keep all the look (styles and formatting) the same, just add ModernCV icons beside my contact info. I tried adding `\usepackage{fontawesome}`,`\usepackage{moderncv}`, `\moderncvicons{awesome}` and then changing the code for the phone number from simply `<phone number>` to `\phone{<phone number>}`, but it didn't work and I'm getting errors like "File `moderncv.sty' not found. \moderncvicons". I am running the newest version of TexStudio. Are there any problems with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this answers your question - use XeLaTeX to compile using the [`fontawesome` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\topmargin=-0.2in
\oddsidemargin=-.2in
\evensidemargin=-.5in
\textwidth=5.8in
\textheight=9.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{{\footnotesize Curriculum Vitae \thepage}}

\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\scshape}
\begin{document}


\name{$\langle$Name here$\rangle$ \hspace{3.85in} Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{resume}

\section{Contact Information}

\vspace{.05in}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3.75in}p{2in}}
$\langle$Address Line 1$\rangle$ & \faPhone~$\langle$phone number here$\rangle$ \\
$\langle$Name of School$\rangle$ & \faEnvelopeAlt~\texttt{\href{mailto:<email here>}{$\langle$email here$\rangle$}} \\
$\langle$City, State, Zip$\rangle$ & \faLaptop~\texttt{\href{$\langle$website here$\rangle$}{$\langle$website here$\rangle$}} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Education}

\section{Teaching}

\section{Employment}

\section{Research}

\section{Last updated} November 15, 2014

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

For symbol selection, see the [`fontawesome` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.pdf).

---

If you "really like" that CV, the copy-and-paste the code, and change things to suit your needs.

Comment: That looks great! I'm only getting one error though: "** WARNING ** Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map"." Does this error message mean anything to you? I'm using the newest version of TexStudio.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: Surely not when you compile my example code?

Comment: Yes, when I compile your code in TexStudio I get the error `** WARNING ** Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map".`

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: Does the same happen when you compile the following minimal example with XeLaTeX? `\documentclass{article}\usepackge{fontawesome}\begin{document}\faPhone\end{document}`

Comment: Oops, I noticed you have a typo in "package". But yes, I ran the minimal example and got the same exact error message!

Comment: @EthanAlvaree That's not an error message, but a warning which is not relevant for you unless you need to typeset Japanese. Update your TeX distribution and it will go away.

Comment: @egreg: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: Updated my TeX distribution. It works! Thank you!